# Is there any way to improve Gmail's new compose?

Tags: gmail

I like the general idea behind the new compose but I hate how hard it is to get to the formatting controls. I'm somebody who constantly does funny indents, manually links and quotes things.

The new formatting bar that has to be clicked first is painful. I have a ton of screen space.

Does anybody know of a gmail-install or browser-installed extension that would allow a permanent formatting bar at the top of the body - more like the old compose screen?

Comment: You may want to see if there's a GreaseMonkey script.  If you're not familiar with GreaseMonkey, it's an extension for Chrome and FF that allows you to install custom JavaScripts to enhance existing sites.

Comment: @AdamPlocher That's what I was thinking when I I said browser-installed extension.

Comment: Or it's time to switch to an alternative: http://alternativeto.net/software/gmail/

Comment: @endolith Seems a little extreme.

Comment: @Oli: I guess, but this isn't the last change they're going to make.  By the time you find a solution to fix the new compose window, Google's going to downgrade something else, and then by the time you fix that, there will be no Gmail left; it'll just be *Google+ Messaging*.

Comment: I'd at least like a script to keep the "Formatting options" bubble open at all times.  That shouldn't be too hard, right?

Answer (score 2):

What about that Chrome-extension: [Retro Compose for Gmail™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/retro-compose-for-gmail/npjkmbechijncoapeeifgfhcjkcandgk)?

However I would prefer a userscript because I'm usually not using Chrome.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about how the extension works/solves the OP's problem. Thanks.

Comment: The extension gets rid of the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome / Firefox extension that will provide the old Gmail compose UI. See [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/49536/47698).

Comment: Despite the one person thinking otherwise, this solution *is* useful. The OP is (rightfully) complaining about the new compose, and asks about available extensions that alter the UI. A user visiting here, wishing they had their old experience back, and looking for a way (given that Gmail give them now choice) to "improve gmail compose", would be greatly interested to know that they do in fact have the option to revert. Perhaps you are a Google acolyte? Or maybe Jason Cornwell himself?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Retro Compose](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/retro-compose-for-gmail/npjkmbechijncoapeeifgfhcjkcandgk/) (Chrome) and [Old Compose](http://oldcompose.com/) (Chrome+Firefox), there is a third Chrome extension that improves Gmail's new compose by getting rid of it:  [Fix Compose for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fix-compose-for-gmail%C2%AE-to/hpoidnelefpoofhdioielagfklahfcjg/).

[image]