# How to disable Gmail's new editor?

Tags: gmail

Apparently Google wants to break Gmail again: They switched off the old editor today for everyone and made  their new editor (see [this help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2645922)) mandatory which does top-posting and allows no fixed text font.

How can I get the old plain text editor back? I found no config option for that.

Comment: Not possible; there is no way to get it back.

Comment: The [Retro Compose](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/retro-compose-for-gmail/npjkmbechijncoapeeifgfhcjkcandgk) extension for Google Chrome can bring it back

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be disabled, but there is a great new extension (currently just for Chrome, more on the way apparently) that gives you the old compose UI experience back. It can be found here:

[oldcompse.com](http://oldcompose.com)

[...or link to the Chrome webstore if you don't want to be coerced into tweeting/facebooking about it](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/old-style-compose/fnnjcgahiapokddlkccpabpaajolelie)

I just tried it, and it seriously works :-)

Attached image is an example of something I just wrote....

[image: Gmail compose experience with new extensional installed under Chrome]

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on the arrow icon in the lower-right corner of the *Compose* window;
   [image]
2. Choose **Plain text mode** form the menu.
   [image]

---

As for switching back permanently to the old compose, it won’t be possible anymore:

> Now that that option is available, we're saying farewell to the old compose and switching everyone to the new compose over the next few days.

[Source](https://plus.google.com/+Gmail/posts/Pkrnsy8yEPx).

Comment: That's not the old editor.

Comment: You want the old editor or the plain text editor?

Comment: The old plain text editor. That switch is needed for _every_ mail and it still does top-posting.

Comment: No, it isn’t, once you choose it, it will switch to plain text for every email you compose until you switch it back to rich text.

Comment: Not satisfied. Google also broke [It's all Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) for GMail, which let's me use vim.

Comment: Not exactly their fault; the add-on author(s) should update their app to make it work with the new Gmail compose system.

Comment: No. The old editor used a `textarea`; the new one is a "rich text editor". See this [FAQ](https://github.com/docwhat/itsalltext).

Comment: @MartinSchröder The add-on should also be looking for elements that use the role="textarea" option. Things are modernizing here, the add-on needs to stick with the times if it wants to continue to be current. Why do you want to use vim with textareas anyway? You're using the online version of GMail, why not use a command line based mail client and retrieve emails to your GMail via IMAP  and then you can do all the vim editing you want.